# Customizing UITabBarItem

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to customize UITabBarItem where I need to add a custom image but its a circular image  and the boundary should expand beyond the UITabBar where it should display some of the parts of the button in the UIView of the application.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check out https://github.com/xhan/PlutoLand and run it.

you can find a custom `PLTabBarController` which allow you custom your TabBarItems there